# GET the value of the selected option using php then show it with echo

Tags: php, html

I'm Beginner on PHP, Javascript, I would like to  get selected value from select/option and stock it into a php variable  ( $varpeoplesnames ), to use it in a future SQL request and show it with echo

my code:

```
<select name="peoplesnames">
  <option value="1">john</option>
 <option value="2">sarah</option>
 <option value="3">samantha</option>
</select>
<?php   (....)    echo $varpeoplesnames;
```

How can I get the text of the selected option to show it with echo in php?

Comment: You either need to initiate a new request to send this value to PHP, or use AJAX

Comment: How can I initiate request to send this value to PHP, or use AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a form with action being the link to your php file and a submit button

HTML:

```
<form action='yourPhpFile.php' method='GET'>
    <select name="peoplesnames">
        <option value="1">john</option>
        <option value="2">sarah</option>
        <option value="3">samantha</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit'></input>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
$varpeoplesnames = $_GET['peoplesnames'];
echo $varpeoplesnames;
?>
```

Comment: thanks, there is another solution without using  <input type='submit'></input> (echo the value just after selecting a value)?

Comment: @user3546104 you need to use javascript for that